# Interesting infinite products

Tags: calculus

I have found the following products but numerically it seems to work but they are difficult to calculate the conergence could be demonstrated by taking limits
$$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(1+e^{i \pi  2^{k-1}} q^{2^k}\right) \left(1+e^{3 i \pi  2^{k-1}} q^{2^k}\right)=\frac{1}{q^2+1}$$
$$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1+e^{3 i \pi  2^{k-1}} q^{2^k}}{1+e^{i \pi  2^{k-1}} q^{2^k}}=\frac{q+i}{-q+i}$$
$$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((-1)^{2^k} q^{2^k}+e^{i 2^k}\right) \left(1+(-1)^{2^k} e^{i 2^k} q^{2^k}\right)}{\left(q^{2^k}+e^{i 2^k}\right) \left(1+e^{i 2^k} q^{2^k}\right)}=-\frac{\left(-q+e^i\right) \left(-1+e^i q\right)}{\left(q+e^i\right) \left(1+e^i q\right)}$$
$$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{\left(-1+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \pi  3^k} q^{3^k}\right)^2 \left(e^{i \pi  3^{k+1}} q^{2\ 3^k}+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \pi  3^{k+1}} q^{3^k}+1\right)}{\left(-1+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \pi  3^{k+1}} q^{3^k}\right)^2 \left(e^{i \pi  3^k} q^{2\ 3^k}+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \pi  3^k} q^{3^k}+1\right)}\right)^{3^{-k-1}}=\frac{q+i}{-q+i}$$
especially the latter I have not been able to calculate it numerically for 0<q<1

Comment: How did you find them?

Comment: The exponentials seem a lot of clutter to me. Take the top equation for example: for $k=0$ you have two simple complex conjugate terms $(1+iq)(1-iq)=1+q^2$ and for $k>0$ the exponentials simply dissapear because the argument is a multiple of $2\pi$. Things become a lot simpler then.